# How can I lower the volume specific to a particular app?

Tags: settings, applications, sound

I use the app Workrave to help keep RSI at bay. However, the app has a higher sound volume than I'd like, while the rest of my system is just right for me. Is there a way I can lower its volume while keeping my system's volume as it is?

Answer (score 2):

You can install pavucontrol :

`$ sudo apt install pavucontrol`

In the Playback tab you can choose the volume output for each audio stream.

[image]